# Haskell: How to pipe the contents of one handle into another in real time

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I am writing a program that runs an external sub process interactively and I need the contents of the output handle to be output to stdout as soon as it is available. I have tried something like this:

```
main = do processInfo <- createProcess (proc "ghci" []){std_out = CreatePipe,
                                                    std_in  = CreatePipe }
       case processInfo of
          (Just hIn, Just hOut, _, _) -> do mainloop hIn hOut
                                          hClose hIn
                                          hClose hOut
       _                              -> do error "Unable to start process"

mainloop :: Handle -> Handle -> IO ()
mainloop inh outh = 
    do ineof <- hIsEOF outh
       if ineof
          then return ()
          else do inpStr <- hGetLine outh
                  putStrLn inpStr
                  mainloop inh outh
```

But this doesn't work since it only recognizes output line by line, so any output on the processes output handle that isn't terminated by a newline doesn't show up. I have tried the same thing with hGetContents but it produces the same result. I have read through the documentation of both System.Process and System.IO and haven't really found anything conclusive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hSetBuffering` is what you're looking for, the default (on Unix at least) is line buffering.  Use it on the stdin before starting the main loop

```
hSetBuffering hIn NoBuffering
```

and optionally also on the output handle if you want to see the results immediately on the output side.  Note, however, that disabling buffering can quite drastically decrease performance.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even think of changing the buffering mode on stdin/stdout.

Comment: It's worth noting that the default on Windows is different to the default on Linux so it's worth setting the buffering type anyway to get consistent behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

I'm very much a Haskell newbie, but I remember coming across an example recently of processing input character-by-character. Is [hSetBuffering](http://www.zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputio/hSetBuffering_f.html) possibly what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Buffering is one thing, but you are also using `gGetLine` which will wait for a whole line (or end of file). Consider using `hGetChar` if you really want to read one character at the time.
And btw, another way of overcoming buffering is to use `hFlush`.